# How to make an object inherit a value?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Given something like this:

```
data = {'car': {'name': 'Mazda'}, 'year': 2006};
```

Is there a way to get to the "2006" value using **data.car.name.year**

I am trying to use the attribute of the parent when an object itself is missing that attribute. I looked int to **prototyping**, but it doesnt seem to be it ?

In other worlds, how to access values that are defined at a parent level if not available at the level requested ?

Comment: Seen your structure, 
To get "2006" : data.year
To get "Mazda" : data.car.name
You should read a bit about JSON to get more familiar with element nesting.

Comment: In this case, 'car' and 'year' are not children of data, but rather properties, which don't have a hierarchical relationship in that manner. The type of 'car' is itself an object, which has no relationship with data.

Comment: Given your existing structure, it can't be done because an object can be referenced by many other objects or variables, so there would be no way for it to know which one you want. With prototypal inheritance it wouldn't work either because they can't be circular. You could make an explicit circular reference on the object itself, but then you need a property added to the nested object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get year ("2006") of that object you need to access like this:

```
data.year
```

But it is recommended to change your object to:

```
data = {'car': {'name': 'Mazda','year': 2006}};
```

And access:

```
data.car.year
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking.

Comment: Yep, hi asked about "Is there a way to get to the "2006" value using data.car.name.year" I'm telling that with that object no, because It has another structure

Comment: The question isn't clear, but what he is actually asking isn't how to get "2006", but rather how to access values that are defined at a parent level.

Comment: Just use parent.propertyName then? If the property does not exist on the parent, it will return undefined

Comment: @Alan you are correct that is what my question is. how to access values that has been defined at a parent level, if not defined at current level.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't do data.car.name.year is due to the rules of JSON. If you break this out, you can see it a bit better.

**OPTION 1:**

```
data = {'car': 
    {
        'name': 'Mazda'
    }, 
    'year': 2006
};
```

Now you can see that if you access `car`, you then are directed to the object it contains with `name` in it. Treat it like a folder structure on your computer.

/car/name = {'name': 'Mazda'}
/car/year = 2006

Maybe what you want instead is this:

```
data = {
   'car': 
    {
        'name': 'Mazda',
        'year': 2006
    }
};
```

This way you can do `data.car.year`

**OPTION 2:**

`data.car.name.year = data.year`
This will duplicate the property on the object but then you can use it as `data.car.name.year`

**Another more complex way:**

You can have objects inherit from other objects in javascript. I would suggest going for ES6 Classes or TypeScript.

Both will need to be compiled into javascript to be run in most browsers for the latest features.

From typescript deep dive:

```
class Point3D extends Point {
    z: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number, z: number) {
    super(x, y);
    this.z = z;
}
add(point: Point3D) {
    var point2D = super.add(point);
    return new Point3D(point2D.x, point2D.y, this.z + point.z);
    }
}
```

Here is a similar straight JS implementation

```
var Point3D = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Point3D, _super);
    function Point3D(x, y, z) {
    _super.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
}
Point3D.prototype.add = function (point) {
    var point2D = _super.prototype.add.call(this, point);
    return new Point3D(point2D.x, point2D.y, this.z + point.z);
};
    return Point3D;
})(Point);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why I got downvoted? I would love to hear some constructive feedback. Doing my best to help you out :)

Comment: Objects inheriting from other objects is far from painful `var child = Object.create(parent)`, and there are other ways too. Though the question asked is, given the structure described, can a referencing object be accessed from the referenced object, and the answer is *no*, and it doesn't have anything to do with JSON, which is a text-based data transmission format.

Comment: I agree that it is far from painful. I will re-word that.